# Mass rotating on a vertical circular path

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

I am considering the following exercise:

*Let's consider a mass moving on a vertical rigid hoop, subjected only to the force of gravity. What are the equations of motion?*

[image: Body moving around a vertical hoop]

I know that there is a simple way of solving this exercise (it is just a variation of a pendulum, where the string is replaced by a rigid circular rail). However, I would like to know where my reasoning is faulty.

There are two forces acting on the body, the gravity which pulls it down and the reaction from the track that pulls it towards the center. The reaction is equal and opposite to the radial component of the force of gravity. Therefore, the net force acting on the body is the tangential component of the gravity:

$$
|F| = mg\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\right) = mg\sin(\theta)
$$

Projecting onto the Cartesian axes (here is where I know I am complicating my life, but still I want to know where the argument breaks):

$$
\begin{array}{rl}
m\ddot x &= -mg\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta) \\
m\ddot y &= -mg\sin^2(\theta)
\end{array}
$$

Notice that these equations make sense: if the body is at the bottom of the hoop, there is no acceleration since the gravity force only has a radial component, which is canceled by the reaction from the hoop. Therefore, both $\ddot x$ and $\ddot y$ are zero.
When $\theta=\pi/2$, the gravity has only a radial component, therefore $\ddot x=0$ and $\ddot y=-mg$. Finally, the vertical acceleration is always negative, while the horizontal acceleration is negative for negative angles, and positive for positive angles.

I need to relate $\theta$ to $x$ and $y$. I know that

$$
\begin{array}{rl}
 x &= R\sin(\theta) \\
 y &= -R\cos(\theta)
\end{array}
$$

where $R$ is the radius of the rigid hoop.

Deriving twice w.r.t time I get

$$
\begin{array}{rl}
\ddot x &= R\ddot\theta\cos(\theta) - R\dot\theta^2\sin(\theta) \\
\ddot y &= R\ddot\theta\sin(\theta) + R\dot\theta^2\cos(\theta)
\end{array}
$$

Equating these equations with the accelerations found above, I get

$$
\begin{array}{rl}
g\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta) &= -R\ddot\theta\cos(\theta) + R\dot\theta^2\sin(\theta) \\
g\sin(\theta)\sin(\theta) &= -R\ddot\theta\sin(\theta) - R\dot\theta^2\cos(\theta)
\end{array}
$$

If the terms proportional to $\dot\theta^2$ weren't there, both equations would give me $g\sin(\theta)=-R\ddot\theta$, which is the equation of motion for a pendulum. This is what I would expect.

However, the term proportional to $\dot\theta^2$ looks suspicious. Not only because it would give me a motion different from the pendulum, but also because it makes the two equations above incompatible! I somehow have the feeling that this term must be cancelled by some extra terms I missing. But I do not know what exaclty I am missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is really that you are missing a force. If it is a string that enforces the circular motion, it would be tension. In your case, the normal reaction force from the rigid hoop onto the mass.

When the mass is not moving on the hoop, there is no $\dot\vartheta$ and so it is ok to ignore the radial acceleration part. But when the mass is actually moving, the hoop normal reaction force and gravitational force must, together, provide centripetal acceleration, and your equations are missing that part. If you included that part, you would have gotten agreement.

Comment: Isn't the hoop normal reaction force equal and opposite to the radial acceleration force? So that it cancels the radial gravitational part, leaving with only the tangential part of the gravitation. In this way the body only experiences a tangential force and therefore moves in a circular motion?

Comment: That is a mistake, and the whole point of my answer. If you want to decompose to Cartesian, then you must keep track of the radial acceleration, that is NOT zero once the mass is moving tangentially. If you purely study the tangential, angular parts, then, and only then, can you ignore the radial acceleration.